# Error building Maliit with glib and dbus dbus_g_value_build_g_variant

Tags: ubuntu, build, makefile, glib, dbus

I am trying to build Maliit ( https://wiki.maliit.org/Documentation/Installing ) on Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit. I have an Ubuntu 12.04 machine as well and building Maliit works just fine out of the box on the newer Ubuntu but I need to have it build on 10.04.

I had several earlier errors on 10.04 that after Googling turned out to be due to an outdated version of glib. So I grabbed the latest version and built like this:

```
cd /home/$user/Desktop
wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.33/glib-2.33.12.tar.xz
unxz glib-2.33.12.tar.xz
tar xvf glib-2.33.12.tar
cd glib-2.33.12
mkdir build-x86
cd build-x86
mkdir /home/$user/glib-2.33
../configure --prefix=/home/$user/glib-2.33
make
make install
export PATH=/home/$user/glib-2.33/bin:$PATH
cp -r /home/$user/glib-2.33/bin/* /usr/bin
cp -r /home/$user/glib-2.33/share/* /usr/share
cp -r /home/$user/glib-2.33/include/* /usr/include
cp -r /home/$user/glib-2.33/lib/* /usr/lib
cp -r /home/$user/glib-2.33/lib/*so* /lib/
```

The build is nearly succeeding but now I am stuck on the following error:

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/Desktop/maliit-framework-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_1_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Release/examples/apps/gtk2'
g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-rpath,/home/pclass/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib -o maliit-exampleapp-gtk2 .obj/exampleapp-gtk.o    -L/usr/X11R6/lib ../../../lib/libmaliit-glib-1.0.so -L/home/pclass/glib-2.33/lib -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lpangocairo-1.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0 -lXext -lX11 -lm
../../../lib/libmaliit-glib-1.0.so: undefined reference to `dbus_g_value_build_g_variant'
../../../lib/libmaliit-glib-1.0.so: undefined reference to `dbus_g_value_parse_g_variant'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Desktop/maliit-framework-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_1_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Release/examples/apps/gtk2'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Desktop/maliit-framework-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_1_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Release/examples/apps'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Desktop/maliit-framework-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_1_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Release/examples'
make: Leaving directory `/home/user/Desktop/maliit-framework-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_1_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Release'
make[3]: *** [maliit-exampleapp-gtk2] Error 1
make[2]: *** [sub-gtk2-make_default] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-apps-make_default] Error 2
make: *** [sub-examples-make_default-ordered] Error 2
13:48:42: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building project maliit-framework (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Specifically the error boils down to:

```
../../../lib/libmaliit-glib-1.0.so: undefined reference to `dbus_g_value_build_g_variant'
../../../lib/libmaliit-glib-1.0.so: undefined reference to `dbus_g_value_parse_g_variant'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea what this means and Google is not turning up anything helpful. I think it may have to do with Glib and dbus. What is the issue and how can I fix this? Please help me resolve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling fails because it can't find the `dbus_g_value_build_g_variant()` function, that function first appeared in [dbus-glib 0.88](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/dbus/2010-August/013257.html) , but **Ubuntu 10.04** ships with [dbus-glib 0.84](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libdbus-glib-1-2) so that is the problem.

By the way, **dbus-glib 0.88** bumped its glib requirement to **glib-2.24** but that is not a problem for you as you are installing **glib-2.33** .

You need to install **dbus-glib 0.88** to fix that compile error.